# Print on terminal for a long time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am extremely new to python and because i was bored, I built a simple password generator

code:

```py
import random

upper = "ABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ"
lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxwyz"
numbers = "1234567890"
symbols = "><{}[]()!@#$%^&*:"

all = lower + upper + numbers + symbols
length = 16

password = "".join(random.sample(all, length))
print(password)
```

I used pyinstaller to convert it into an exe
then when I run the exe it opens up a terminal shows for half a second the password and closes.
How do i make it "print for a long time" so that it is useable, specifically i want to make it stay open until the user closes it?

Answer (score 0):

```py
...
print(password)
input('Press Enter to exit...')
```